# Progress openedge 4gl to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

What is the best way or approach to transfer my data from progress open edge 4gl to Amazon Cloud S3 bucket?

It would have billions of data in one go & if we consider daily transfer then it would be hundreds of thousands

Comment: Billions of what? Bits? Bytes? Rows? Files?

Comment: Billions of rows